# Blue glow around astronaut

Tags: optics, scattering

What is causing the apparent blue tinge around the astronaut and the instrument in these images taken from Apollo 12?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Source: [NASA archive](https://history.nasa.gov/alsj/a12/images12.html) (Images AS12-46-6826, AS12-46-6816, AS12-46-6847)

Comment: This is probably better dealt with on [photo.se].

Comment: I agree that this is probably not a physical effect around the astronaut/instrument, but rather an effect called [haltion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Anti-halation_backing) which can occur around very bright objects photographed with analog film. Normally the effect gives a red glow, but the blue glow here might be due to some special emulsion used on the Moon.

Comment: The instrument is not glowing, and the lower part of the figure very little.. I am amazed that the aura people have not picked up on this ! an equally exotic explanation here http://www.orgonelab.org/astronautblues.htm . I would guess the costume is not absolutely air tight, and this is light scattered from the leak from the costume. My guess would be confirmed from pictures of present day astronauts, where the air leaks should not exist with present techology. An experiment of a leak could be made.

Comment: @annav Your suggestion (which really should have been posted as an answer) does not explain the glow around the bright light due to the [opposition effect](https://atoptics.co.uk/atoptics/oppos1.htm) in the third photo.

Comment: @rob  It is a playful guess.  The picture you link may be entirely a different effect. Reflection from the ground .We have to wait until   they land on the moon again,

Comment: @anna The site you linked talks of [Orgone](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Orgone) energy which seems to be a fallacy.

Comment: @Shub  that is why I named it "exotic", at the same level with auras

Comment: [Here's](https://youtu.be/ESAPg7w3wm8?t=2710) an explanation that says it's due to the dust kicked off by the astronaut while walking though that doesn't quite explain the second and the third pictures.

Comment: Also, dust particles are likely to scatter all wavelengths of light unless the size of lunar dust is small enough.

Answer (score 1):

This looks like a common photographic issue.  Note that these are very bright objects with dark backgrounds.

A lens is a complex optical instrument and light does not restrict itself to just conveniently passing through glass from the front to the back.  It can reflect off internal surfaces - the lens body or the glass surfaces.  This results in glare-like issues like these.  It can even reflect off the film (or sensor now) to produce these effects.  Obviously the brighter the source the more light will be reflected and bounced around.  These reflections are bright enough to appear in the image when the eventually bounce back to the film or sensor.

Modern optics have quite good control over these issues thanks to the development of better lens coating and sophisticated computer modelling of optics but can still show these effects.

Comment: except the instrument is not glowing, and it *is* reflecting light as seen in the second photo.

Comment: @annav Not sure what you mean.  It's visible so it's reflecting light.  Geometry matters in this effect.  The glow effect is, in my experience of photography, not usual with lenses of that era.  The coatings are simply not as good as modern ones.  I'm not seeing anything here I haven't seen hundreds of times in my own amateur photography, especially with older lenses.  I (alas) haven't had a chance to try it on the Moon.

Comment: The lens distortions you are taliking about should also be equally around the instrument on the right, and they are not. The instrument is equally reflective.

Comment: @annav My experience with some older photographic prime lenses is that they show this effect primarily in the center (not that they didn't have glare issues other than that, but this specific effect was usual in the center).  I suspect it has to do with a flat rear element, but that's just my impression. I've seen no technical analysis saying that.  Somewhere I have a now unused old Nikon 50mm f1.4 which was very prone to this central blue glow effect, something I detested as I like contra-light photography.  It was otherwise very good for it's day.  Geometry of scene and lens are issues here.